# Bing maps invalid credentials (Win Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm writing a simple WP 8.1 app which handle travel routes. I've created a key in Bing Maps Dev Center and I have a valid key. I set it in XAML for Map control:

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name="map" MapServiceToken="valid token"/>
```

In the app, I can search locations by addresses (MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync) but I  get an InvalidCredentials result when try to find a route between the addresses with MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone 8.1 map control doesn't use Bing Maps. You have to get a map token to use these maps from the Windows Phone dev center. Here is documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn741528.aspx

In Windows 10 this map control is updated to use Bing Maps.

Comment: Oh, WP7 used Bing Maps and WP10 will so, but 8.1 doesn't. :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's correct. Getting the WP7 map control to support offline required a major rewrite. There wasn't enough time to do this before the release of WP8. Nokia ended up providing the map control for WP8/8.1 as they had one that supported offline.